# How to remove broken nodes in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster with one master and two nodes.
For some reason, a node became unreachable for the cluster so all pods were moved to the other node. The problem is that the broken node keep in the cluster, but i think the master should remove the node automatically and create another one.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 12):

**I option:**

If you work on GKE and have HA cluster, node with **NotReady** state should have been automatically deleted after couple of minutes if you have autoscaling mode on. After a while new node will be added.

**II option:**
If you use kubeadm:

Nodes with state **NotReady** aren't automatically deleted if you don't have autoscaling mode on and HA cluster. Node will be continuously check and restart.

If you have Prometheus check metrics what happened on your node which has NotReady state or from unreachable node execute command:

`$ sudo journalctl -u kubelet`

If you want node with **NotReady** state to be deleted you should do it manually:

You should first drain the node and make sure that the node is empty before shutting it down.

`$ kubectl drain <node name> --delete-local-data --force --ignore-daemonsets`

`$ kubectl delete node <node name>`

Then, on the node being removed, reset all kubeadm installed state:

`$ kubeadm reset`

The reset process does not reset or clean up iptables rules or IPVS tables. If you wish to reset iptables, you must do so manually:

`$ iptables -F && iptables -t nat -F && iptables -t mangle -F && iptables -X`

If you want to reset the IPVS tables, you must run the following command:

`$ ipvsadm -C`

You can also simply shutdown desire node:

`$ shutdown -h`

The **-h** means halt while now clearly means that the instruction should be carried out immediately. Different delays can be used. For example, you might use +6 instead, which will tell the computer to run the shutdown procedure in six minutes.

In this case new node will **not** be added automatically.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

I have another situation, it is in AWS EKS, the nodes have been terminated from AWS Console, then i found the EKS nodes can't be deleted by command `kubectl delete node <node_name>`

Finally I understood that nodes stuck at deletion due to [**finalizer**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/finalizers/)

Follow up below steps, you can clean the nodes out of the cluster

#### try to delete nodes with status of `NotReady`, but can't get rid of them.

```
$  kk get nodes
NAME                                                 STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ip-192-168-103-252.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal   NotReady   <none>   26h   v1.22.6-eks-7d68063
ip-192-168-106-14.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal    NotReady   <none>   26h   v1.22.6-eks-7d68063
ip-192-168-126-54.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal    NotReady   <none>   26h   v1.22.6-eks-7d68063
ip-192-168-128-106.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal   Ready      <none>   43m   v1.22.6-eks-7d68063
ip-192-168-179-235.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal   Ready      <none>   12h   v1.22.6-eks-7d68063
```

So when you run `kubectl delete node` on above 3 `NotReady` nodes, they can't be deleted.

#### Cordon the node

```
$ kubectl cordon ip-192-168-103-252.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
```

#### Drain the node

```
$ kubectl drain ip-192-168-103-252.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal --force --ignore-daemonsets
```

If you run the `kubectl delete node <node_name`, these nodes still can't be deleted.

#### clean the finalizer

```
$ kubectl patch node/ip-192-168-103-252.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":[]}}' --type=merge
```

#### Delete the node

now you can delete it

```
$ kubectl delete node ip-192-168-103-252.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal 

$  kk get nodes
NAME                                                 STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ip-192-168-128-106.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal   Ready      <none>   43m   v1.22.6-eks-7d68063
ip-192-168-179-235.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal   Ready      <none>   12h   v1.22.6-eks-7d68063
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks for sharing. It saved me.
I am testing Karpenter with EKS, but made some mistakes on the security group, so the nodes can't been reached by the API controller, thus get lost at the end.

In such case, the VM is already gone. We can't logon to it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Cordon the node
2. Drain the node
3. Delete the node
4. Reset the node ( run kubeadm reset command  if it is joined using
   kubeadm)
5. Join the node again as a fresh node

Answer (score -1):

As soon as node becomes unreachable by network, e.g. stops responding to pings - master will automatically remove such node from cluster.

You can delete node manually by:

```
kubectl delete node NODE_NAME
```

Comment: But the master doesn't remove it automatically. If i execute (after some hours) _kubectl_ _get_ _nodes_ the node keep showing and the status is NotReady

Comment: shutdown the node and master will remove it.