# how do I delete unreachable node

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes.  I built three nodes and then realized that I messed up and deleted them.  Now when I attempt to add new nodes, I cant because it keeps complaining about the nodes I have already deleted.  When I attempt to delete them manually I keep getting:

```
kubectl delete node ks01
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.21.30.165:6443: connect:network is unreachable
```

How can forcefully delete the nodes or clean up the cluster to be able to start over?

Comment: Does this thread answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064537/how-to-remove-broken-nodes-in-kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

1. First Mark the Node as unschedulable to prevent new pods from being assigned to it:

```
kubectl cordon <node_ID>
kubectl drain <node_ID>
```

2. Then try to delete it

```
kubectl delete node <node_ID>
```

Comment: doesn't matter what command I type.  I have tried all three above.  I keep getting the same thing ```Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.21.30.165:6443: connect: network is unreachable```

Comment: are you able to reach kube-api, and execute any kubectl command?

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and removed the .kube/config file and then started over.  This seemed to have worked for me.